# Rcpp plugin for C++11 not working since update to R 3.4.0

Tags: r, c++11, rcpp

Since I updated R to the new version 3.4.0, the Rcpp plugin to enable C++11 does not seem to work properly. (Note that this is a different situation as reported here http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/R-3-4-has-broken-C-11-support-td4732692.html)

I have C++ files requiring C++11 standard that I compile in R via Rcpp using the command `Rcpp::sourceCpp(foo.cpp)`. The R default standard is C++98 but I could change that by adding the following command in my C++ file
`// [[Rcpp::plugins("cpp11")]]`

This does not work anymore with the new version of R 3.4.0, my compiler use the default standard (C++98) instead of C++11, despite the plugin. It used to work with previous version of R.

My solution for the moment is to set an environment variable for my R session:
`Sys.setenv("PKG_CXXFLAGS"="-std=c++11")`

Here is the configuration I use in R:

```
sessionInfo()

R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-suse-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: openSUSE Leap 42.2

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so
locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8

 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C

 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.0  rsconnect_0.4.3 tools_3.4.0
```

I use the Rcpp package version 0.12.1.0.
My compiler is the following:

```
~$ g++ --version | head -n1
g++ (SUSE Linux) 4.8.5
```

Am I missing something? Has anyone else encountered the same issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That was reported yesterday at the [GitHub issue tracker in #683](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/683) and already closed in [pull request #684](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/pull/684) which has now been merged.

So just upgrade to the master branch, or set the env.var manually for now. It is an upstream R change that broke this with no provision for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! That fully addresses the issue here.

Comment: Glad it helps, and thanks for accepting the answer. Feel free to also upvote by clicking on the upward-facing triangle.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According [Dirk Eddelbuettel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43638082/4393334)  answer -- just insert

```
# R code
Sys.setenv("USE_CXX11" = "yes")
sourceCpp("code.cpp")

# C++ code
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]                                                                       
double myhypot(double x, double y) {
return std::hypot(x,y);
```

}

... and it really works !

Comment: You should not need that under a current version of Rcpp.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind advice ... and it also really works !